# Using rescore when building queries with Spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to make use of [rescore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-rescore.html) when building a query with Spring data elastic? I'm using Spring boot 1.4.0.RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch has a [RescoreBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/rescore/RescoreBuilder.java) class that you can use to do this.

Comment: No worries, glad it will help.

Comment: How is it used?

Comment: this link shows 404 error.